# Pricing condition not working in widget section for Product showing from Backend

Tags: product-list, widget, magento-2.2.5, product-prices

I'm trying to create widget from backend for showing the particular some product list in home page.

[image]

But when i'm giving pricing condition like below, the condition is not working and the UI portion going blank.

[image]

How to solve this issue. Please help. Is this condition workable?
Please suggest me any option. Thank You

Comment: Please help anyone. I stuck all over the day.

Comment: Hi, really I'm unable to solve this, didn't find any clue or any suggestion for this. Felling like weird. Any help will be very useful for me for this. Please any suggestion? Is there any way to giving condition for this?

Comment: Hello, I didn't get any response. Is this a bug in magento 2 that what I found.